# Registering a class from an unreferenced assembly with castle windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I've decoupled all my windsor installers to their own IOC assembly.  It's possible to register types from an unreferenced assembly like so.

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Web")
        .BasedOn<IController>()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

    Classes
        .FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Web")
        .BasedOn<IBaseHttpModule>()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest()
    );
```

This works fine for me at the moment but I'd like to explicitly state the order in which my modules are registered.

I've tried the following but have figured that this can't work because MyProject.Web can't be referenced in my IOC dll as this would create a circular dependency.

```
        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IBaseHttpModule>()
                .ImplementedBy(Type.GetType("MyProject.Web.Modules.AuthenticationModule, MyProject.Web"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                );
```

Is there a way to get this kind of thing to work with windsor, I've searched the docs and the dlls in the object browser but I've not found anything that looks like it'll be my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
container.Register(
Classes
    .FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Web").Where(t => t.FullName == "MyProject.Web.Modules.AuthenticationModule").
    .BasedOn<IBaseHttpModule>()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
```

Comment: Yeah, I bet that this will work.  I've done this kind of thing for picking up all classes that end with service.  Thanks!  Will mark as correct when I test it

Answer (score 0):

Use an [installer factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx) to control registration order.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installer in the unreferenced assembly then make Castle Windsor pick it up like this:

```
container.Install(FromAssembly.Named("MyProject.Web"));
```

I think this is a cleaner approach because you don't deal with registering implemenations in another assembly, they do it themselves.

Comment: I take your point, but I hate having installers all over the place hence why I've moved them all into their own Ioc project.

Comment: This is also something I have done in the past. It means each assembly has its own "windsor installer" and is responsible to install itself when the IoC asks. I quite like the fact that the installer sits next to the implementation. It also means if you share the assembly / module with totally different team it comes with the specific windsor installer inside. Self installing if you like. But Neil's point is still valid and it can be a matter of preference.